# XSLT compile error for using MemoryStream

Tags: c#, asp.net, xslt

I am creating an xslt and xml file dynamically to show my questionnaire & save my question options (for dropdown). Now I want to use stream instead of writing on actual file. So this is how I am doing it:

```
XmlReader xslt_reader;
XmlReader xml_reader;

PageLoad(){
  Fn_CreateXSL();
  Fn_CreateXML();
  LoadQuestionnaire();
}

Fn_CreateXSL(){
   xslt_stream = new MemoryStream();

   XmlTextWriter objXSLTWriter = new XmlTextWriter(xslt_stream, Encoding.UTF8);

   objXSLTWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
   objXSLTWriter.WriteStartDocument();
    ..........
   objXSLTWriter.WriteEndDocument();
   xslt_stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
   xslt_reader = XmlReader.Create(xslt_stream);
}

Fn_CreateXML(){
   xmlt_stream = new MemoryStream();

   XmlTextWriter objXMLTWriter = new XmlTextWriter(xmlt_stream, Encoding.UTF8);

   objXMLTWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
   objXMLTWriter.WriteStartDocument();
    ..........
   objXMLTWriter.WriteEndDocument();
   xmlt_stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
   xmlt_reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlt_stream);
}

LoadQuestionnaire(){
  XslCompiledTransform var_xsl_trans = new XslCompiledTransform();

  // also tried var_xsl_trans.Load(xslt_reader, null, new XmlUrlResolver());
  var_xsl_trans.Load(xslt_reader); // XSLT Compile Error occurs

  StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

  var_xsl_trans.Transform(xml_reader, null, sw);
}
```

But I am getting "XSLT Compile Error when I'm trying to load it. Any idea?

Comment: You haven't shown us where the two Fn_* functions are used, nor what's assigning a value to xslt_reader. It would really help if you'd provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: i am calling those functions on page load (i've modified my question). and about xslt_reader I am assigning value in Fn_CreateXSL [or did you mean sth else?]

Comment: Well, a short but complete console app would make this a *lot* simpler to diagnose.

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry don't understand how to make it better, the actual codes are more than 400 lines

Comment: Add objXMLTWriter.Flush() before the xmlt_stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); - edit - had the wrong object for the Flush()

Comment: @Kevin cool dude... it fixed my issue, having some other issue now. Anyway if you post your comment as answer I'll accept it. Could you explain why I have add flush() ?

Comment: @Black: In future, you'd do some work to convert it into something short but complete. We don't need the full program - *just* enough to demonstrate the problem. I strongly suspect that the shortest valid XSLT transform you can think of and a tiny XML file, loaded from a console app with just a `Main` method, would have shown exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @kevin mentioned in the comment, the following fixed my issue, but I am not quite sure why it worked though (have some idea, but not sure)

> Add objXMLTWriter.Flush() before the xmlt_stream.Seek(0,
>   SeekOrigin.Begin);

Answer (score 1):

Here is the approach that works for me.

Instead of using XmlWriter->MemoryStream->XmlReader I would use `XElement` introduced by Microsoft with LINQ in .NET 3.5. Both `Load` and `Transform` methods of `XslCompiledTransform` class have overloads which take `IXPathNavigable` as a parameter to pass XML. This interface has only one method `XPathNavigator  CreateNavigator()` and `XElement` has such method. I do not know why Microsoft did not declare that `XElement` implements this interface. Probably they forgot :-). So, to compensate this oversight I implemented 6 line converter class `XNavigable`. You will see it below. Here is an analog of Page_Load() of the OP:

```
public void Generate()
{
    XElement inputXml = CreateInputXml();
    XElement transformXslt = CreateTransformXslt();

    XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
    transform.Load(new XNavigable(transformXslt), null, null);

    MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream(); 
    transform.Transform(new XNavigable(inputXml), null, outputStream);

    byte[] outputBytes = outputStream.ToArray();
    string outputString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(outputBytes);
}
```

I use `MemoryStream` instead of `StringWriter` because StringWriter was always creating for me UTF-16 encoded XML as output. I think UTF-16 is imposed by StringWriter because underlying string has 16-bit per character. With MemoryStream we are in control of encoding.

For completeness here is the code for my `CreateInputXml` and `CreateTransformXslt` methods. They are just examples. Of course, `XElement.Add()` methods can be used to generate content. I just used constructors with all nodes listed in them to hardcode quickly.

```
    private static XElement CreateTransformXslt()
    {
        //XSL to substitute <placeholder/> with <realElement/> and copy everything else.
        //<stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        //  <output indent="yes" />
        //  <template match="@* | node()">
        //    <copy>
        //      <apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        //    </copy>
        //  </template>
        //  <template match="placeholder">
        //    <realElement xmlns="" />
        //  </template>
        //</stylesheet>
        XNamespace xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform";
        XNamespace empty = "";
        XElement transformXslt = new XElement(xsl + "stylesheet", new XAttribute("version", "1.0"),
            new XElement(xsl + "output", new XAttribute("indent", "yes")),
            //new XElement(xsl + "strip-space", new XAttribute("elements", "*")),
            new XElement(xsl + "template", new XAttribute("match", "@* | node()"),
                new XElement(xsl + "copy",
                    new XElement(xsl + "apply-templates", new XAttribute("select", "@* | node()"))
                )
            ),
            new XElement(xsl + "template", new XAttribute("match", "placeholder"),
                new XElement("realElement")
            )
        );
        return transformXslt;
    }

    private static XElement CreateInputXml()
    {
        XElement origXml = new XElement(new XElement("Root",
                                            new XElement("Child1", "data1"),
                                            new XElement("placeholder"),
                                            new XElement("Child2", "data2")));
        return origXml;
    }
```

One gotcha in the code above is that we should not use `xsl:strip-space elements="*"` in the XSL. It is commented above. This is because `XslCompiledTransform` has problems stripping space when the input xml is passed as `IXPathNavigable`. In an error message it was suggesting using `XmlReader` if I need stripping. I do not think that stripping space is important for generating a web-page.

Finally, here is the converter class mentioned in the beginning:

```
class XNavigable : IXPathNavigable
{
    XElement _xElement;
    public XNavigable(XElement xElement)
    {
        _xElement = xElement;
    }

    public XPathNavigator  CreateNavigator()
    {
            return _xElement.CreateNavigator();
    }
}
```